# i want to send mail with html body and attachment in shell script

Tags: bash, email, unix, sendmail

while executing this script i got a row attachment, i got a blank zip file but my existing zip file ok it don't have any issue. please someone help me to solve this issue i had tried a lot from net but its not working.

```
export BODY=test.html
(
echo "To:"xyz@abc.com;
echo "Subject:QC Count failed report Please find Attachment.";
echo "MIME-Version: 1.0";
echo "Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary=\"B835649000072104Jul07\"";

echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
echo "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit";
echo "Content-Disposition: inline";
echo "";
echo "";
cat $BODY
echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";
echo "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$FAILED_ZIP\"";
echo "--B835649000072104Jul07";

) | sendmail -t
```

Comment: What about your content type ? Have you checked with application/zip ?

Comment: ya i checked it but its  not working.

Comment: are you recieving email sent

Comment: i am receiving mail with html body but without zip file

Answer (score 1):

What about using the swaks command and attaching your zip ?

```
swaks -t "abc@xyz.com" -f "noreply@example.com" --header "Subject: QC Count failed report Please find attached" --body " Here are results" --attach /path/to/the/zip/file
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working for my server command not found error but you don't get my problem . i want to send html body with zip file attachment.:)

Comment: You would have to download it on your server before you can use here is the link : http://www.jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/   After you download you can do --body /path/to/html/file . That way it would cover your html body and also you will have your zip attached with the attach flag --attach /path/to/zip/file